# Cannot Pull b/c "You have unstaged changes", but status says there are no changes

Tags: git

I'm working with a developer here who is seeing a weird issue that I've never encountered before. He's working on a repository and needs to pull the latest changes from someone else before he can push. All of his changes are committed.

```
$ git pull
Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

Which seems reasonable enough until...

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Say what?

I've tried `git reset --hard HEAD` before pulling, but the pull still fails.

Only one guy is seeing this and he's on a Mac (OSX 10.6.8). Any ideas? I'm about to pull my hair out.

Comment: What value do you get if you run `git config branch.autosetuprebase`? If it is set to `always` that might explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of

```
git pull
```

try

```
git fetch
git rebase -p origin/master
```

If that doesn't work you can try

```
git pull --no-rebase
```

***How to check why this message occurs***

Make sure you on a branch, not a detached head. Rebasing doesn't work on a detached head.

Run the following commands, the result should be no output.

```
git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
git diff-files --ignore-submodules
git diff-index --cached --ignore-submodules HEAD --
```

Comment: Interesting. Only the merge (`git pull --no-rebase`) worked. Any idea why a merge would work, but a rebase wouldn't given the reason that's being stated and the apparent working directory status? Going to mark this answered, but I'd like to understand more so I can try to fix his underlying issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobWilkerson I updated the solution with some checks you can run why you got this message.

Comment: Meant to add that output is empty as expected.

Comment: Argh my mistake, the git diff files should be run without --quiet

Comment: "Rebasing doesn't work on a detached head." says who? Works for me all the time.

Answer (score 9):

Are you working on local filesystem or nfs share?

I had exactly the same problem when I was working on nfs share.

I have added `noatime` option to the `mount` command and it helped:

```
mount -t nfs -o noatime,... device dir
```

Comment: Exactly my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for me issue was with files in secure folder

1. only this command has shown that there are files unstaged

   ```
   git diff-files --ignore-submodules
   ```
2. de-configure git-crypt and re-encrypt files in work tree

   ```
   git-crypt lock
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try for $ git stash then try for git pull.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I tried to rebase a repo owned by root (and I was an unprivileged user).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there might be a rebase in progress. Try running `git rebase --abort` first.

More forceful methods to clean out the local include

- Delete all files in the working directory (excluding the .git directory, of course)
- `git clean -d -x -f`    (`-d`: directories, `-x`: ignored files, `-f`: force. Replace `-f` with `-n` for dry run)

And then follow up with a `git reset --hard` and `git checkout`.

One more thought is to try a `git reset --hard HEAD~N` - i.e resetting a number of commits back, and hoping the pull will work and fast-forward the local.

Comment: Thanks, @chamila_c, but I've tried that as part of my trial and error campaign. No joy.

Comment: How about a 'git fetch' - does that at least update the local copy of the remote?

Comment: `git fetch` works fine, but unfortunately has no impact when I try a later pull.

Comment: See my response to Peter van der Does. In fact a merge (`git pull --no-rebase`) does work, but I'd love to understand why. Seems to me that he's still got something funky going on in his repo that I'd like to get sorted out so he can rebase again.